# Replace all tab stops' positions in MS Word

Tags: vba, tabs, cpu-word

I have a document with 4 tabs: 1cm, 5cm, 9cm and 13cm.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there are some paragraphs having all 4 tab stops while some have 2 stops (1cm and 9cm) or 1 stop (1cm). Some paragraphs don't have any stops (like Question 1,2,3)

I want to write a VBA that changes all current tab stops but doesn't add any extra stops in 2-stop and 1-stop paragraphs.

It should be like:

```
*find all 1cm stops and change into 1.5cm stop
find all 9cm stops and change into 9.5cm stop
and so on.*
```

I have tried recording a macro doing the task and working the code out but still haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Thank you schlebe for making the suggestions. The reason why I had some <br> in the previous post is that it had looked like a single paragraph in the preview panel. Had no idea it turned out to be separate paragraphs. The code shouldn't have been in that frame as it is not actually kind of codes but just what I thought it should be like. Anyway, "tabstop" is an official word but you can just refer to it as simply as "tab".

Comment: I'm surprise that nobody has answered to your question. So I have searched and found a solution that I will explain below in answer part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following VBA Word code

```
Private Sub ReLocateTabStop(nFindPos As Single, nReplacePos As Single)

Dim oParagraph As Word.Paragraph
Dim oTabStop As Word.TabStop

For Each oParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    For Each oTabStop In oParagraph.TabStops
        If Abs(oTabStop.Position - Application.CentimetersToPoints(nFindPos)) < 0.1 Then
            oTabStop.Position = Application.CentimetersToPoints(nReplacePos)
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

This routine (Sub) search in all paragraph a tab with a specific position.

When it is found, Position is changed.

Tips:

I use `Application.CentimetersToPoints()` to convert `Centimeters` in `Decimal` so that I can compare with Position properties with `Points` as unit.

I use `Abs()` and `Round()` functions because `Position` in `TabStops` is not equal (float equality) to number of centimeters given in parameters !

Example:

TabStop is set to 2 centimeters and Position contains 56.7 points.
But Application.CentimetersToPoints(2#) return ... 56.69291

I use following code to test it

```
Public Sub TestReLocateTabStop()
    Call ReLocateTabStop(1#, 1.5)
    Call ReLocateTabStop(9#, 9.5)
End Sub
```

The `#` character is automatically added for integer number.

I have tested what I wrote and it works.